# serviceworker location is wrong when integrating PWA to .NET Web Application using WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, web-essentials

I am trying to integrate PWA to my .NET Web Application using WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA .

I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/introduction-to-pwa-in-asp-net-core-application-da96c7cc4918

I have done everything that is mentioned in this tutorial. But I am getting following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

When I looked the doc of WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA : https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker][2](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker)

The following line is supposed to be added above `</body>` tag

```
<script>'serviceWorker'in navigator&&navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker')</script>
```

instead of this line mine has following line

```
<script nws-csp-add-nonce='true'>'serviceWorker'in navigator&&navigator.serviceWorker.register('~/serviceworker')</script>
```

As you can see path of my serviceworker is wrong ('~/serviceworker') . How can I fix this path error of service worker?

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/86), check your service worker's path at `index.html` whether relative or absolute. It is stated [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/446#issuecomment-355893849) that if you're using a local repository then while specifying the URL or path of your file, don't specify the absolute path instead give an absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because of the tilde `~`

A workaround is like this:

*Disable* registering the service worker and manifest:

```
services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions
{
RegisterServiceWorker = false,
RegisterWebmanifest = false,
OfflineRoute = "offline"
});
```

Then, you can manually add them in _Layout (where *manifest.webmanifest* is your *webmanifest.json* file under *wwwroot*)

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest" />
```

And finally add the service worker

```
<script>'serviceWorker' in navigator && navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker')</script>
```